# Не выполняется js функция возвращенная ajax запросом

Tags: jquery, ajax, функции, копирование

Есть страница, на которую после загрузки фотографии с помощью ajax, возвращается загруженная картинка. Хочу сделать, что бы по клику по кнопке, копировалась нужная мне информация(путь до изображения).
**Проблема в том, что не срабатывает функция копирования, после того как элементы подгрузились через ajax.**
Вот функция копирования(загружается сразу, при открытии страницы):

```html
<script>
  function copytext(el) {
    var $tmp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($tmp);
    $tmp.val($(el).text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $tmp.remove();
  }
</script>
```

Которая вызывается с помощью клика по кнопке(подгружается через ajax):

```html
    <button type="button"  onclick="copytext(\'#image'.$name.'\');">Копировать</button>
```

*Текст, который нужно копировать, соответственно так же возвращается ajax запросом.*
Читал похожие проблемы, но  так и не получилось правильно применить найденные ответы.
Если кто-то сможет помочь, буду очень признателен.

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: Не работает функция copytext(), если кратко. Кнопка с onclick подгружается через ajax, из за этого не работает эта функция(на сколько я понял). Вот не знаю как исправить:( В других случаях, когда нет ajax запроса, все работает отлично

Comment: У Вас в `"copytext(\'#image'.$name.'\');"` синтаксически неверный код. Что Вы там сказать хотели?

Comment: После того, как приходит ответ от сервера(когда картинка загружается) в браузере отображается что-то вроде этого: "copytext('#image1617124773-4453915841');" - это разве синтаксически неправильно, если в итоге подставляется в функцию нужный мне идентификатор?

Comment: Приведите весь код или его аналог, чтобы тут видно было как именно не срабатывает. А то самое интересное вы словами рассказываете и нужно телепатировать что там в консоли.

Comment: Что значит "Не работает функция copytext()"? Не вызывается? Вызывается, но ничего не делает? Вызывается и выдает ошибку? Добавьте в `copytext`: `console.log(el, ' - ', $(el).length, '-', $(el).text());`

Comment: Добавил, в консоли выводит вот это `#image1617285278-7020257465  -  1 - /img/pages/1617285278-7020257465.jpg` . Это текст, который должен скопироваться

Comment: @Igor Получается функция вызывается, но ничего не делает. Хотя когда кнопка с вызовом функции `copytext('#image1617124773-4453915841');` выводится не через ajax запрос, то все работает.